# Displaying multiple 'mat-error' validation in template driven form

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

**How to display  single error correctly on validating multiple errors using ng if else in template driven form.**

```html
<form>
    <mat-card>
               <mat-card-content>
            <mat-form-field>
            
                <input id="email" name="email" #ref_email="ngModel" matInput type="email" email placeholder="Email" [(ngModel)]="email" required>
                
                <mat-error *ngIf="!ref_email.valid && ref_email.errors.required">
                    Email is required
                </mat-error>
                
                <mat-error *ngIf="!ref_email.valid && ref_email.errors.email">
                    Email is not valid
                </mat-error>
                
            </mat-form-field>
        </mat-card-content>        
    </mat-card>
</form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

First of all even on template driven forms you need to reference your form with a html property something like this:  `<form #userForm="ngForm">` 
 After that you can check to the errors of the referenced form:

```
                <mat-error *ngIf="userForm.controls['email']?.errors?.required">
                    Email is required.
                </mat-error>

                <mat-error *ngIf="userForm.controls['email']?.errors?.email">
                    Email is not valid.
                </mat-error>
```

Comment: first line `*ngIf="*ngIf="`